# Using a layered design pattern in C# and ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a junior software engineer at a mid-end company and I've come up with something that I fail to grasp (the docs are pretty scary to read), I'm sorry if i skipped some already made questions like this one, but I want a direct answer that answers my questions.

I'm using a design pattern called DDD for my C# ASP.NET Core web project, what I fail to understand are those two layers called `Persistance` and `Services`.

As far as I understand:

- The `Services` layer is where the data is manipulated
- And in the `Persistance` layer under repository is what fills the data

Is that correct?

So looking at more in-depth into an existing project that already uses this layered pattern, what I see is that both in `Persistance` layer and `Services` layer, the data is getting manipulated.

In the `Service` layer you have classes like `ProductServices` that are implementing methods from an interface `IProductServices`, public methods like delete, save, search, etc.

And in the `Persistance` layer you have classes like `ProductRepository` that are implementing those same methods from an interface `IRepository`.

What's the deal? This is something that I can't get, sorry if this might sound confusing to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use *"manipulates the data"* to describe these layers. Yes the can both manipulate data, but in different context.

**Persistence** handles the storage and retrieval of data (basic)

**Services** makes changes to the data from the business perspective

Comment: So i can think of Services something that is not part of simple CRUD methods, basically a layer where i can change / manipulate the same data.

Comment: @codefom it can be part of the CRUD process, just different context

Comment: Okay so i think i got my doubts cleared, need to practice on this, thank you Yorro